# res.format.html not working with paginate module

Tags: node.js, express, pagination

I am using the [express-paginate](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate) module and I am running into some issues around the `res.format` section in my routes file. I am wondering why this portion is causing the paginate to not be found when I render my view file.

error message:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/views/pages/blog.ejs:7
    5| 
    6| <body>
 >> 7| 
    8|  <header>
    9|      <% include ../partials/header %>
    10|     </header>

paginate is not defined
    at buf.push.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="paginate">
        .
    </div>

    <footer>
        .buf (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:34:125)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:35:23)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:37:67)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:255:15
    at Object.exports.render (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:293:13)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:323:20)
    at View.render (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:517:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:955:7)
    at Object.res.format.html (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/app/routes.js:70:13)
```

routes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

//index
    router.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var drinks = [
            {   name: 'Bloody Mary', drunkness: 3 },
            {   name: 'Martini', drunkness: 5 },
            {   name: 'Scotch', drunkness: 10}
        ];

        var tagline = "Lets do this.";

        res.render('pages/index', {
            drinks: drinks,
            tagline: tagline
        });
    });


app.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));


//blog
    router.route('/blog') 

        // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Blog created.' });
                });

        }) // END POST method


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {

                if (err) return next(err)

                    Blogpost.find(function(err, blogpost) {
                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);

                        blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
                        blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
                        blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
                        blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post

                        res.format({
                            html: function() {
                                res.render('pages/blog', {
                                    blogpost: blogpost,
                                    pageCount: pageCount,
                                    itemCount: itemCount
                                })
                            },
                            json: function() {

                                res.json({
                                    object: 'blogpost',
                                    has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                    data: blogpost
                                })
                            }
                        }); // END res.format(html, json)
                    }) // END Find Blogpost 
            }); // END Blogpost.paginate
        }); // END GET method


    //Route for individual blogs
    router.route('/blog/:blogpost_id')

    // START GET method blog by ID  
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blog) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(blog);
        });
    }) // END GET method blog by ID

    // START PUT method
    .put(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post

            blogpost.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);


                res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
            });

        });

    }) // END PUT method

    // START DELETE method
    .delete(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.remove({
            _id: req.params.blogpost_id

        }, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });



//about
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/about');
    });


module.exports = router;
```

paginate.ejs:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-1">
        <div class="paginate">


                <ul>
                <% if (paginate.hasPreiousPages) { %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<%=paginate.href().prev %>">Previous</a>
                    </li>
                <% } %>

                <% if (paginate.hasNextPages) { %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<%=paginate.href().next %>">Next</a>
                    </li>
                <% } %>
                </ul>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

blog.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div class="body-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><%= blogpost.title %></h2></td>
                        <td><h3><%= blogpost.author %></h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="paginate">
        <% include ../partials/paginate %>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second line of your routes.js file, you are calling

```
var app = express();
```

This line creates a new express app.
Then you use the paginate middleware on this new app,

This is not the 'running' app, you can find the main app instance in your app.js

All your requests are handled by the app created in app.js, this way the paginare middleware never gets called.

To fix this

1: remove these two lines from routes.js

```
var app = express();

var paginate = require('express-paginate');
```

2: add in app.js (before you load your routes)

```
var paginate = require('express-paginate');
app.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));
```

Or if you only want to use pagination for that specific set of routes, 
remove

```
var app = express();
```

and use

```
router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));
```

Comment: Hey @MarkMeeus. Thanks for the explanation. This fixed my initial error and now I can render my pagination, but now I have an issue where I click on the next button and given a `Cannot GET /undefined` page. Is this an issue coming from the route formatting?

Comment: try paginate.href() for the link to the next page and paginate.href(true) for the link to the previous page

Comment: still not doing it. The previous link isn't showing up, which is correct, because I'm on the first page, but I still get the same error. Would this be a common error message from the modeling or routing?